# :not() selector not selecting element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following string and I want to ignore just strong tag from the string using css selector:

```
<p><strong>Local:</strong><br>
-Brasília/DF </p>
```

I tried the following syntax but it doesn't work.

```
p:not(strong)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can only accept one answer to a question at a time. This is not your first question and you should be aware of this. Please make up your mind which answer you want to accept.

Comment: Yaah.... this time sorry!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pseudo-class, attached to an element `p:not(strong)`, selects from those elements to which it is 'attached' (here the `p`); and a `<p>` element is *always* not a `<strong>` element; therefore this selector will always match every `<p>` element.

You seem to be trying to style the parent `<p>` element based on its child `<strong>` element which cannot work, as CSS has no parent-selector (see: "[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)")

You could, instead, add a class (or other attribute) to the `<p>` element, and use that in the selector:

```
<p class="hasStrongDescendant"><strong><strong>Local:</strong><br>
-Brasília/DF </p>
```

And style with:

```
p:not(.hasStrongDescendant) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

```css
p:not(.hasStrongDescendant) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>A paragraph with no child elements</p>

<p class="hasStrongDescendant"><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br>-Brasília/DF</p>
```

Or, using a `data-*` attribute:

```
<p data-hasChild="strong"><strong>Local:</strong><br>
-Brasília/DF </p>
```

And style with:

```
p:not([data-hasChild="strong"]) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

```css
p:not([data-hasChild="strong"]) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<p>A paragraph with no child elements</p>

<p data-hasChild="strong"><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br>-Brasília/DF</p>
```

Also, if you wrapped the contents of the `<p>`, following the `<strong>`, inside their own element you could style the descendants of the paragraph using the negation selector:

```
<p>A paragraph with no child elements</p>

<p><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br><span>-Brasília/DF</span>
</p>
```

Styling with:

```
p :not(strong) {
  /* note the space between the
     'p' and the ':not()' */
  color: #f90;
}
```

```css
p :not(strong) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<p>A paragraph with no child elements</p>

<p><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br><span>-Brasília/DF</span>
</p>
```

Two further approaches, assuming that you want to style the text of the child outside of the `<strong>` element is (the simplest):

```
/* define a colour for the <p>
   elements: */
p {
  color: #f90;
}

/* define a colour for the <strong>
   elements within <p> elements: */    
p strong {
  color: #000;
}
```

```css
p {
  color: #f90;
}
p strong {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<p>A paragraph with no child elements</p>

<p><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br>-Brasília/DF</p>
```

And a slightly more complex version, using CSS generated content:

```css
p {
  color: #f90;
}
p[data-label]::before {
  content: attr(data-label) ': ';
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p data-label="Local">-Brasília/DF</p>
```

References:

- [CSS negation pseudo-class (`:not()`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: I haven't seen a more contrived workaround than that data-attribute. It's one of those "if it works, it works" things...

Comment: @BoltClock: yeah; it's *really* not pretty but the point was to try and show an alternative form of selector being used with `:not()`, rather than looking nice as such; the only way I'd personally attempt the above is the use of `p :not(...)` though it does require additional elements. Having said that, I'd also be tempted to style the whole `<p>` and move the 'label' ('Local') into a data-attribute and then use pseudo-elements instead.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class works.  It matches an element that is not represented by the argument.

So in this case to select text of `p` but not the `strong` tag you can wrap other part of text in `span` and then select all children of `p` but not `strong` like this

```css
p :not(strong) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Local:</strong><br>
<span>-Brasília/DF </span></p>
```

Other option is to simply select text of `p` and then overwrite `strong` tag with default style.

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
p strong {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Local:</strong>
  <br>-Brasília/DF</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything but the strong tag will use CSS. Like:

```css
.just_this :not(strong){
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<p class="just_this">
  <strong>Local:</strong>
  <br /><span>-Brasília/DF</span>
</p>
```

Alternative(just use the [child-combinator '>'](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)):

```css
.just_this{
  color:blue;
}

.just_this>strong{
  color:black;  
}
```

```html
<p class="just_this">
  <strong>Local:</strong>
  <br />-Brasília/DF
</p>
```

Comment: "Something like this" What is this? The "just_this" class has no relation to the strong whatsoever. Why would you have a negation with the class on the strong in the first place?